# Growing a hardware RAID-10 array

Tags: raid, windows-sbs-2011, raid10

I am interested how to grow a RAID 10 array on Windows SBS 2011 machine? Basically I have added two additional disks, expanded array and now I want to grow my c: filesystem to take advantage of new space?

It is hardware RAID, Controller is Smart Array P410i 512Mb on HP server. The move was from  RAID1 (2 disks, 300Gb) to RAID10 (4disks, 600Gb)

Thanks

Comment: Need a bit more information, such as what controller are you using? How big are you making the C:\ drive? You have a 2TB limit with MBR.

Comment: Also, how many disks do you have already?

Comment: @Cole I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot to [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net) or [Partition Magic Free](http://partition-magic-free.com/windows-server-2011/resize-sbs-2011-system-partition.html) (or other similar utilities)to extend the disk space in the Windows OS.

Comment: am I in danger of loosing any data?

Comment: No, it *should* work fine without loosing data. *Should*. Unless the power fails midway. Or something else which was unexpected happens. So always have a recovery strategy and up-to-date backups. Having said that: No, there should be no data loss.

Comment: @Hennes how to check that the cache battery is connected and fully charged?

Comment: @John I believe the HP Array Configuration Utility should allow you to see that information.

Comment: This can actually be done in sbs 2011 without any additional software. It is a two click procedure in manage storage section